# Apollo not returning relational object on create

Tags: prisma

I have the following Mutation:

```js
Mutation: {
  createMessage: async (_, args) => {
    const x = await prisma.message.create({
      data: {
        message: args.message,
        user: {
          connect: {
            id: Number(args.userId)
          }
        },
        session: {
          connect: {
            id: Number(args.sessionId)
          }
        }
      }
    })
    console.log(x)
    return x
  },
},
```

I create new message and connect it to a user and a session.
This is the typeDef:

```
type Message {
  id: ID,
  message: String
  user: User
}

type Mutation {
  createMessage(
    sessionId: ID!
    userId: ID!
    message: String!
  ): Message
}
```

But when I create a message the log on the server shows:

> { id: 23, message: 'This is a message!', userId: 100, sessionId: 6 }

Do I need to change something to include the `User` and `Session` relational objects in the create mutation?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy:

```js
Mutation: {
  createMessage: async (_, args) => {
    const x = await prisma.message.create({
      data: {
        message: args.message,
        user: {
          connect: {
            id: Number(args.userId)
          }
        },
        session: {
          connect: {
            id: Number(args.sessionId)
          }
        }
      },
      include: {
        user: true
      }
    })
    console.log(x)
    return x
  },
},
```

Just add the `include`.